# Why balance update before sending token is a root cause of Reentrancy attack?

Tags: vulnerability

I am guessing that sending token makes contract inconsistent state, and it enables reentrancy attack to the attacker. Why balance update before sending token is a root cause of Reentrancy attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the classic reentrency attack that looks like:

```
function withdraw() external {
    uint256 depositedAmount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    payable(msg.sender).sendValue(depositedAmount);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
}
```

The reason why updating the balance after sending the funds creates a vulnerability is because it's possible to call withdraw() from a contract with a [fallback function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.11/contracts.html?highlight=fallback#fallback-function) that calls withdraw() again ...

```
receive() external payable {
    if (address(bankContract).balance > 0) {
      bankContract.withdraw();
    } else {
      payable(owner()).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
  }
```

So, the execution has not completed and as far as the Bank contract is aware, the user still has positive balance available. Thus this cycle will repeat until either:

- the gas limit of either the initial transaction, or the block is reached, or
- the Bank contract is drained of all Ether

However, if the Bank contract was simply written like this ...

```
function withdraw() external {
        uint256 depositedAmount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
        payable(msg.sender).sendValue(depositedAmount);
    }
```

The exploit is not possible. That's because calling the function back again (via `fallback()` or `receive()`) will not trigger another withdrawal, and that's because the user's balance is set to zero before the attacker's contract receives the first withdrawal, which triggers the second call to `withdraw()` ... with the modified `withdraw()` code, the contract knows that the user's balance has already been withdrawn, even though it's execution may not yet be finished.

For a more detailed explanation of how this works, please see this great example for more about this:

https://github.com/dappuniversity/Reentrancy-attack-Smart-Contract-Security

The best way to prevent these types of attacks is to remember to use the [check-effects-interaction](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.11/security-considerations.html) pattern when developing smart contracts. Essentially, your state-changing calls should occur at the end of your function.

The example that I have chosen to use is a Bank contract that stores Ethereum, but the same logic applies to contracts that are handling  ERC20 token deposits and withdrawals.

Answer (score 0):

A reentrancy attack happens when a contract calls an external contract before it has finished executing. If the external contract is malicious and has a fallback function, it could call back into the original contract, potentially before state changes (like updating a balance) have been completed. This can lead to inconsistencies and allow an attacker to drain funds or otherwise abuse the contract.

In the specific case of a token transfer, imagine a contract that first sends the tokens and then updates the balance. If the receiver of the tokens is a malicious contract, it could use the token transfer as an opportunity to call back into the original contract and request more tokens. Since the original contract hasn't yet updated the balance, it might believe that the malicious contract still has tokens to withdraw, leading to the tokens being drained.

The way to prevent this is to make sure that all internal state is updated before making any external calls. This is known as the "Checks-Effects-Interactions" pattern. This pattern advises that checks (such as access controls and verifying preconditions) should be done first, then effects (updating state variables) and finally interactions (calling other contracts).

Here's a simple example:

```
function withdraw(uint amount) public {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount);

    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;  // Effect

    (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call.value(amount)("");  // Interaction
    require(success, "Transfer failed.");
}
```

In the example above, the contract first checks that the sender has enough balance, then it reduces the sender's balance, and finally, it sends the tokens. This way, even if the receiving contract is malicious and calls back into the withdraw function, it won't be able to get any additional tokens because the balance has already been updated.